# SQL query with field value for left join in column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to get the results I want with one query from those tables?
The problem is that I suspect that since the name of the code is only in column name, it will be impossible.

```
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+
| unioncode | qt | productCode | brandCode | shopCode |
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 00212AA   | 10 |           3 |         2 |        1 |
| 00212AA   | -4 |           3 |         2 |        1 |
| 00212AA   |  3 |           3 |         2 |        1 |
| 00372BC   |  7 |           6 |         4 |        1 |
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+

+------+-------------+---------+
| code | description |  type   |
+------+-------------+---------+
|    1 | BuyTech     | shop    |
|    2 | Apple       | brand   |
|    3 | iPhone      | product |
|    5 | Samsung     | product |
|    6 | Smartphone  | product |
+------+-------------+---------+
```

I'm struggling to create a query to get the result I would like as follow:

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| unioncode | totQt | productName | brandName | shopName |
+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 00212AA   |     9 | iPhone      | Apple     | BuyTech  |
+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 00372BC   |     7 | Smartphone  | Null      | BuyTech  |
+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Have you thought about moving products, brands, shops. . . Into their own tables? This doesn’t answer your question... it just seems managing that single lookup table is a bit wild.

Comment: Yes @Brien but since the project is working and is not something I built, I must go on with the stuff they already have.

Comment: bummer. Well this isn’t an impossible problem. I’m away from my computer. Someone will certainly give you the grouping and sum logic to find your answer.

Comment: Check My answer I Thinks its better and Understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should join three times the second table.

And I'm sorry but there isn't brandCode = 4.

> ```
> create table t1 (unioncode varchar(10), qt int, productCode int, brandCode int, shopCode int);
> insert into t1 values
> ('00212AA', 10, 3, 2, 1),
> ('00212AA', -4, 3, 2, 1),
> ('00212AA',  3, 3, 2, 1),
> ('00372BC',  7, 6, 4, 1);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> create table t2 (code int, description varchar(20), type varchar(10));
> insert into t2 values
> (1, 'BuyTech', 'shop'),
> (2, 'Apple', 'brand'),
> (3, 'iPhone', 'product'),
> (5, 'Samsung', 'product'),
> (6, 'Smartphone', 'product');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select unioncode, 
>        tot_qt, 
>        tt2.description as productName, 
>        tt3.description as shopName, 
>        tt4.description as brandName
> from
>      (select unioncode, sum(qt) tot_qt, productCode, shopCode, brandCode
>       from   t1
>       group by unioncode, productCode, shopCode, brandCode
>      ) tt1
> left join  t2 tt2
> on    tt2.code = tt1.productCode
> and   tt2.type = 'product'
> left join  t2 tt3
> on    tt3.code = tt1.shopCode
> and   tt3.type = 'shop'
> left join  t2 tt4
> on    tt4.code = tt1.brandCode
> and   tt4.type = 'brand'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> unioncode | tot_qt | productName | shopName | brandName
> :-------- | -----: | :---------- | :------- | :--------
> 00212AA   |      9 | iPhone      | BuyTech  | Apple    
> 00372BC   |      7 | Smartphone  | BuyTech  | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45e8da4163f91b87bab9f002bae1423f)*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't **brandCode = 4**.So the Output is NULL

```
WITH Cte AS
(
     SELECT unioncode,
            qt,
            description,
            (SELECT TOP 1 description FROM Table2 WHERE code=T1.shopCode) AS shopName,
            (SELECT TOP 1 description FROM Table2 WHERE code=T1.brandCode) AS BrandName
     FROM Table1 t1
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2
     ON t1.productCode=t2.code
 )
SELECT unioncode,
       SUM(qt) AS totqy,
       description,
       BrandName,
       shopName
FROM Cte
GROUP BY unioncode, description, shopName, BrandName
```

Output

```
unioncode   totqy   description BrandName   shopName
00212AA     9       iPhone      Apple       BuyTech
00372BC     7       Smartphone  (null)      BuyTech
```

Demo Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/782c5d/29